# angularjs2 29:20 caused by: this._router.navigate is not a function

Tags: angular

I am new in angularjs2 and i try to navigate route but i revived "29:20 caused by: this._router.navigate is not a function"

may code like this

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Component({
selector: 'app-user',
templateUrl: `app/user/user.component.html`
})
export class UserComponent {
constructor(private _http: Http, private _router: ActivatedRoute) { 
}

edit() {
this._router.navigate(['form']);
}
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are suppose to use `Router`, not `ActivatedRoute` to navigate.

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router'

...

constructor(private _http: Http, private _router: Router) {}

...
```

See official [docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html) for more information

**Router:**

> [...] Manages navigation from one component to the next.

**ActivatedRoute:**

> A service that is provided to each route component that contains route
>   specific information such as route parameters, static data, resolve
>   data, global query params and the global fragment.

Comment: Thank for giving response. 
 is it necessary to use Router  ?

Comment: @test, yes, if you want to navigate from inside your code, `Router` is the way to go :)